# liferay authentication from soap

Tags: soap, liferay, liferay-6

I need integrate Liferay (version 6.2) with another service which stores information about users. Communication with service occurs through SOAP.

Is it possible use users from service to authenticate to Liferay?

Answer (score 0):

Liferay integrates with external systems through LDAP already. If you use that interface, you're set. If you need a proprietary API to access user information, you will have some work in front of you.

It might be worth examining the SSO implementation and intercept newly authenticated users on this level: With the user's identity, create or update a Liferay user account on the fly through LIferay's API. To me this looks like the most promising approach from an effort/maintenance point of view, with the little information I have about your situation.

Alternatively you could batch-update all (Liferay-) user accounts from time to time, based on updates in your external system.

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I understand what need:

1- Step 1: User prompted with A login page.
2- Step 2: The credentials entered by the user are checked against a web service (could be any service)
3- Step 3: The user is either logged in or an auth error displayed to the user.

If that's what you need, then create an autologin hook. The code that call the webs service shall live in the autologin hook.

May seem intimidating, but it is trivial: likely liferay comes with a bunch of them: (take one of them as a template)
auto.login.hooks=com.liferay.portal.security.auth.CASAutoLogin,com.liferay.portal.security.auth.FacebookAutoLogin,com.liferay.portal.security.auth.NtlmAutoLogin,com.liferay.portal.security.auth.OpenIdAutoLogin,com.liferay.portal.security.auth.OpenSSOAutoLogin,com.liferay.portal.security.auth.RememberMeAutoLogin,com.liferay.portal.security.auth.SiteMinderAutoLogin